# Error message when PHP form is sent with empty fields

Tags: php, html, forms, field

I have tried many things, but I cannot get a clean HTML or PHP code to prevent a user from submitting a form with empty fields (I don't know if it can be done). I don't think I can do a javascript, because the host of the HTML files strips the HEAD automatically... As of now, the PHP action sends an email with the form results to a normal @ address.
Here is the form , followed by the PHP action (sorry for the bugs I am new to coding PHP):

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.puzzles-et-jeux.com/themes/puzzles-et-jeux/css/view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

        <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Page contact</a></h1>
        <form action="http://www.lesparisettes.com/emailphp/email.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <p><font color="#cc398b"><strong>Besoin d'une information?<br />
      Vous souhaitez recevoir l'un des catalogues de notre collection?<br />
      Le formulaire ci-dessous est a votre disposition pour nous faire part de vos demandes.<br />
      <u>Merci de bien remplir tous les champs de ce formulaire.</u>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="sujet">Sujet de votre message </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="sujet" name="sujet"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="Catalogue Puzzle Adultes" >Catalogue Puzzles Adultes</option>
<option value="Catalogue Puzzle Enfants" >Catalogue Puzzles Enfants</option>
<option value="Photopuzzle" >Photopuzzle - votre puzzle personnalisé</option>
<option value="Professionnel" >Professionnel</option>
<option value="Autre demande" >Autre demande</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="email">Adresse e-mail </label>
        <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Nom et prénom </label>
        <span>
            <input id="prenom" name= "prenom" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>Prenom</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="nom" name= "nom" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
            <label>Nom</label>
        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="numeroclient">Numéro de client </label>
        <div>
            <input id="numeroclient" name="numeroclient" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Adresse complète </label>

        <div>
            <input id="rue" name="rue" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="rue">Rue / Avenue / Voie</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="adresse2" name="adresse2" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="adresse2">Adresse ligne 2</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="ville" name="ville" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="ville">Ville</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="region" name="region" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="region">Province / Region</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="codepostal" name="codepostal" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
            <label for="codepostal">Code postal</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <select class="element select medium" id="pays" name="pays"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania" >Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria" >Algeria</option>
<option value="Andorra" >Andorra</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda" >Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina" >Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia" >Armenia</option>
<option value="Australia" >Australia</option>
<option value="Austria" >Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan" >Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas" >Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain" >Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh" >Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados" >Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus" >Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium" >Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize" >Belize</option>
<option value="Benin" >Benin</option>
<option value="Bhutan" >Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia" >Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina" >Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana" >Botswana</option>
<option value="Brazil" >Brazil</option>
<option value="Brunei" >Brunei</option>
<option value="Bulgaria" >Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso" >Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi" >Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia" >Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon" >Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada" >Canada</option>
<option value="Cape Verde" >Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Central African Republic" >Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad" >Chad</option>
<option value="Chile" >Chile</option>
<option value="China" >China</option>
<option value="Colombia" >Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros" >Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo" >Congo</option>
<option value="Costa Rica" >Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Côte d'Ivoire" >Côte d'Ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia" >Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba" >Cuba</option>
<option value="Cyprus" >Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic" >Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark" >Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti" >Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica" >Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic" >Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="East Timor" >East Timor</option>
<option value="Ecuador" >Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt" >Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador" >El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea" >Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea" >Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia" >Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia" >Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Fiji" >Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland" >Finland</option>
<option value="France" >France</option>
<option value="Gabon" >Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia" >Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia" >Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany" >Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana" >Ghana</option>
<option value="Greece" >Greece</option>
<option value="Grenada" >Grenada</option>
<option value="Guatemala" >Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guinea" >Guinea</option>
<option value="Guinea-Bissau" >Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="Guyana" >Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti" >Haiti</option>
<option value="Honduras" >Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong" >Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Hungary" >Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland" >Iceland</option>
<option value="India" >India</option>
<option value="Indonesia" >Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran" >Iran</option>
<option value="Iraq" >Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland" >Ireland</option>
<option value="Israel" >Israel</option>
<option value="Italy" >Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica" >Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan" >Japan</option>
<option value="Jordan" >Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan" >Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya" >Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati" >Kiribati</option>
<option value="North Korea" >North Korea</option>
<option value="South Korea" >South Korea</option>
<option value="Kuwait" >Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan" >Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Laos" >Laos</option>
<option value="Latvia" >Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon" >Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho" >Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia" >Liberia</option>
<option value="Libya" >Libya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein" >Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania" >Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg" >Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macedonia" >Macedonia</option>
<option value="Madagascar" >Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malawi" >Malawi</option>
<option value="Malaysia" >Malaysia</option>
<option value="Maldives" >Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali" >Mali</option>
<option value="Malta" >Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands" >Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Mauritania" >Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius" >Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mexico" >Mexico</option>
<option value="Micronesia" >Micronesia</option>
<option value="Moldova" >Moldova</option>
<option value="Monaco" >Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia" >Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montenegro" >Montenegro</option>
<option value="Morocco" >Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique" >Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar" >Myanmar</option>
<option value="Namibia" >Namibia</option>
<option value="Nauru" >Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal" >Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherlands" >Netherlands</option>
<option value="New Zealand" >New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua" >Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger" >Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria" >Nigeria</option>
<option value="Norway" >Norway</option>
<option value="Oman" >Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan" >Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau" >Palau</option>
<option value="Panama" >Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea" >Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay" >Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru" >Peru</option>
<option value="Philippines" >Philippines</option>
<option value="Poland" >Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal" >Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico" >Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar" >Qatar</option>
<option value="Romania" >Romania</option>
<option value="Russia" >Russia</option>
<option value="Rwanda" >Rwanda</option>
<option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis" >Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="Saint Lucia" >Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" >Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="Samoa" >Samoa</option>
<option value="San Marino" >San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome and Principe" >Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia" >Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal" >Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia and Montenegro" >Serbia and Montenegro</option>
<option value="Seychelles" >Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone" >Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore" >Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia" >Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia" >Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands" >Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia" >Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa" >South Africa</option>
<option value="Spain" >Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka" >Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan" >Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname" >Suriname</option>
<option value="Swaziland" >Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden" >Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland" >Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syria" >Syria</option>
<option value="Taiwan" >Taiwan</option>
<option value="Tajikistan" >Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania" >Tanzania</option>
<option value="Thailand" >Thailand</option>
<option value="Togo" >Togo</option>
<option value="Tonga" >Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad and Tobago" >Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia" >Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey" >Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan" >Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Tuvalu" >Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda" >Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine" >Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates" >United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom" >United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States" >United States</option>
<option value="Uruguay" >Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan" >Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu" >Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Vatican City" >Vatican City</option>
<option value="Venezuela" >Venezuela</option>
<option value="Vietnam" >Vietnam</option>
<option value="Yemen" >Yemen</option>
<option value="Zambia" >Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe" >Zimbabwe</option>

            </select>
        <label for="pays">Pays</label>
    </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="telephone">Téléphone </label>
        <div>
            <input id="telephone" name="telephone" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="message">Votre message </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="306225" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">
            Generated by <a href="http://www.phpform.org">pForm</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
    <?php
$required = array('sujet', 'email', 'prenom', 'nom', 'numeroclient', 'rue', 'adresse2', 'ville', 'region', 'codepostal', 'pays', 'telephone', 'message');

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
     }
}

    $sujet = $_POST['sujet'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $numeroclient = $_POST['numeroclient'];
    $rue = $_POST['rue'];
    $adresse2 = $_POST['adresse2'];
    $ville = $_POST['ville'];
    $region = $_POST['region'];
    $codepostal = $_POST['codepostal'];
    $pays = $_POST['pays'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $msg = "sujet: \t $sujet \n";
    $msg .= "email: \t $email \n";
    $msg .= "prenom:\t $prenom \n";
    $msg .= "nom:\t $nom \n";
    $msg .= "numeroclient:\t $numeroclient \n";
    $msg .= "rue:\t $rue \n";
    $msg .= "adresse2:\t $adresse2 \n";
    $msg .= "ville:\t $ville \n";
    $msg .= "region:\t $region \n";
    $msg .= "codepostal:\t $codepostal \n";
    $msg .= "pays:\t $pays \n";
    $msg .= "telephone:\t $telephone \n";
    $msg .= "message:\t $message \n";

    $recipient = "xxxx@example.com";
    $subject = "$sujet \t $prenom \t $nom";

    $mailheaders = "From: Site internet PMW <xxx@example.com> \n";
    $mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $email \n\n";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);

    echo "<HTML><HEAD>";
    echo "<title>Merci</title>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body leftmargin=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\">";
    echo "<table width=\"650\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"></br></br>Merci pour votre message, nous l'avons pris en compte. <a href=\"http://www.puzzles-et-jeux.com/\">Revenir a PMW</a></td>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    ?>
```

Comment: You can use inline javascript (it doesn't have to be in the head).

Comment: If it's done with pure PHP, the user MUST send the form. BUT it can be sent to the script itself AND if the fields are right, a redirect could be performed (before outputting anything!). If something is wrong, the form is shown again (and again) with some message

Comment: javascript can be disabled by the user (or edited).. safest way is to always validate your data in php.. but the answer to your question would be very long.. you should take it step by step.. there are a lot of ways of doing this..

Comment: @Jonathan, I couldn't find information on inline javascript anywhere but it seems like an interesting option

Answer (score 4):

Where is the problem? You can just do this:

```
$error = false;
foreach(...)
{
  // set $error = true if empty (I'd also check for invalid values if I were you)
}
if($error)
{
  echo 'error message';
  // display form again using value="$_POST['fieldname']"
}
else
{
  //...
  mail(...);
  echo 'thank you message';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're creating an $error flag, but it doesn't look as if you're doing anything with it.  You should test this $error and show a different HTML result (and forego emailing the results) if it exists.

Comment: Thank you, although I am not sure how to do this yet

Comment: A simple example:

Just before the `'$suject = '` line, add...

`if ($error) {
 echo "<br/>You must complete the form";
 return;
}`

Better yet to add the following after the $error=true line:

`echo "'$field' required. ";`

to make:

`foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
    echo "<br/>'$field' required. ";
     }
}`

This will provide feedback as to which form fields are missing.

Comment: thank you, thanks to you I have an error message in the PHP page that help the person know that the form wasn't completed or sent. I'll keep this solution until a better one shows up

Comment: As for making it "better," my suggestion would be to brush up on basic PHP -- particularly control structures such as `if/then` and `for` loops. With the information you already have, you should be able to craft a page that warns of such errors, allows the user to re-enter info without hitting the back button, etc.  Otherwise, I'm not sure how much "better" you can realistically expect a simple entry form to be.