# form validation using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I have form where the user can enter a a couple of values..say names of 10 fruits.I wanted to check if the names of the fruits entered by the user exist in my database and ,if 1 fruit name does not exist then  an error message saying  x fruit doesnot exist in the database should be shown(either as a message in the same page or as an alert box.)

i knw we have to use javascript for form validation but how to combine javascript and php for this purpose.thanks in advance

Comment: To get you started you'll need to: (a) get values from the form to be validated; (b) post them to server via Ajax; (c) do validation server-side; (d) return results of validation to client (preferably in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format) and (e) render validation results to client.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not going to write it for, but will try to help you fix whatever you HAVE attempted.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: You have to preload the array of fruits, print it in the Javascript code and use it for checkings **or** you have to go to the dark side using AJAX (if you do not want to preload fruits).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use JavaScript. Actually it makes things really complicated (AJAX etc.). The straightforward way without Javascript:

1. User enters data and clicks submit
2. Data is sent to the php script
3. php-script checks validity

   - if not valid: show error message along form
   - else: save or whatever it is you want to do with the data

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,but i want to do the form validation and display the error message on the same page.I think we need javascript or ajax for that like others suggested

Comment: No, you don't need javascript. Just print it on the same page. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446994/error-message-when-php-form-is-sent-with-empty-fields/8447038#8447038

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the item is in the database on the server. So using php.

But you don't need to submit the full form to check for it. You can asynchronously send the values entered using AJAX (so javascript) back to the server let the server do the checking and return the response.

Here's a link to how to do it using jquery http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms/